# Piechart wedge border styling in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, styling, pie-chart, wedge

Adobe's docs describe how to apply an outline to the pie chart by using the mx:stroke element within a PieSeries, however this only changes the border of the entire chart.

How do I add a border around each of the wedges in the chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two properties:

`stroke` (the stroke around the circumference)

and

`radialStroke` (the stroke within the pie chart itself)

If you're successfully setting one then the other is applied in the same manner.

Josh